# De/serialize object with map?

Tags: dictionary, serialization, vector, stl, c++98

Given the struct sample:

```
struct SomeName
{
    SomeName()
    {
    }

    ~SomeName()
    {
    }

    unsigned int Id;
    std::string Name;
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> Todo;
}
```

How can I serialize a std::vector to binary file?

I have tried:

```
bool Save(std::string filename, std::vector<SomeName> &items)
{
    std::ofstream fileWrite;
    fileWrite.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (!fileWrite)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file for writting...\n";
        return false;
    }
    fileWrite.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&items[0]), items.size()*sizeof(SomeName));
    fileWrite.close();
    return true;
}
```

It works to generate the dat file, but when reading it back it always fails because of the std::map inside of it.

I've tried to understand the crash message which is an access violation and it leads me to believe that it doesn't understand how to initialize the map to fill it when read the file back? Or something similar to it I didn't understand it more than that.

> Access violation reading location 0xfeeeff03.

Pointing back to `// <<< THIS LINE`:

```
_Nodeptr _Copy(_Nodeptr _Rootnode, _Nodeptr _Wherenode)
    {   // copy entire subtree, recursively
    _Nodeptr _Newroot = _Myhead;    // point at nil node

    if (!_Isnil(_Rootnode)) // <<< THIS LINE
        {   // copy a node, then any subtrees
        _Nodeptr _Pnode = _Buynode(_Myhead, _Wherenode, _Myhead,
```

> SerializationCpp.exe!std::_Tree,std::allocator >,0> >::_Copy(std::_Tree_nod,std::allocator >,0> >::_Node * _Rootnode, std::_Tree_nod,std::allocator >,0> >::_Node * _Wherenode)  Line 1078 + 0xc bytes  C++

Here is how I read it back:

```
bool Load(std::string filename, std::vector<SomeName> &items)
{
    items.clear();
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file for reading...\n";
        return false;
    }

    SomeName temp;
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof temp))
    {
        items.push_back(temp);
    }
    file.close();
    return true;
}
```

**In resume, how do I serialize/deserialize that struct from/to a binary file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure can't be serialized just by interpreting it as char array because parts of it are referring to dynamic memory. Use some serialization library (e.g. boost serialization or google protobuf).

Alternatively, you may implement serialization routine manually but this very tedious and error prone job:

1. write `ID` to file
2. write `Name.length()` to file
3. write `Name.data()` to file
4. write `Todo.length()` to file
5. for each member of `Todo` write its key and value

Comment: very informative, I was under the impression it was possible because it works as intended without the map.